# Read from resources when running Spark in Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

In my Spark job I read some additional data from resources files.

Some example `Resources.getResource("/more-data")`

It works great locally, and when I run from spark-submit master=local[*] 
I only to need to add --conf=spark.driver.extraClassPath=moredata.

Moving to cluster mode (Yarn) it is no longer able to find the folder.

I tried spark.yarn.dist.files, without help, maybe I need to add something to that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are running spark application in Yarn mode , you have some file resources in more-data folder . Instead of distributing the folder , distribute all the resources .

Depending on the type of resource to be distributed over , we have following options :

**spark.yarn.dist.jars**

spark.yarn.dist.jars (default: empty) is a collection of additional jars to distribute.

It is used when Client distributes additional resources as specified using --jars command-line option for spark-submit.

**spark.yarn.dist.files**

spark.yarn.dist.files (default: empty) is a collection of additional files to distribute.

It is used when Client distributes additional resources as specified using --files command-line option for spark-submit.

**spark.yarn.dist.archives**

spark.yarn.dist.archives (default: empty) is a collection of additional archives to distribute.

It is used when Client distributes additional resources as specified using --archives command-line option for spark-submit.

You can find further information from https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/yarn/spark-yarn-settings.html

Be careful about how you will be accessing the resources .

example : spark-submit --files /folder-name/fileName

The mentioned resource should be accessed as fileName in the code

Comment: Thanks. So I understand that I need to use --spark.yarn.dist.files and provide comma separated files list. Would they will be available then in classpath and can be accessed using Resources?